# Spring boot batch REST request

Tags: spring-boot, rest

I have several controllers that each responds to a particular endpoint. Let's say "GET /api/users/{userId}" and "GET /api/posts/{postId}". I'm implementing another endpoint "/api/batch" that accepts a batch request so that the client could POST an array of APIs to call, such as

```
{
  requests: [
    {
      method: "GET",
      url: "/api/users/1"
    },
    {
      method: "GET",
      url: "/api/posts/1"
    }
  ]
}
```

On Spring boot, inside the batchController, how can I create a Request object based on the url and then dispatch it to the corresponding controller? I know that I could use a HTTP Client or a RestTemplate to call directly the endpoint inside the batchController, but I would like to avoid that because it implies a creation of an extra HTTP request.

Thank you.

Comment: Post your controller. Normally a controller should have close to no logic se you should dispatch your call to a service without passing by the http layer again

Comment: Sounds more like you needing GraphQL.
https://graphql.org/